# Creating a Data Extension via "Copy" or "Create Based on Existing Data Extension" --- Does either require automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, dataextensions, sql

Is there a difference in the "Copy" option for creating a new DE versus "Create based on existing" option. 
In either case, would the created DE update along with the original DE, or will it require an automation to update info?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying a data extension will only work if it is created as standard data extension.
You will not be able to copy a data extension or select the "Create based on existing" option if the source is a filtered data extension.

in case of standard data extension, copying and using Create based on existing" option will serve the same purpose.

I don't believe it is automatically going to update subscribers information as it only copies the column headers nothing else.. no subscriber data is being captured while creating a new DE. you can either manually upload a list or use an automation to fill newly created DE

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know: if I query the original [copied] DE and fire an event to add records to the new DE in automation studio,  is there no need to create a relationship in Contact Builder?/Will the records automatically map to the correct fields?

Comment: Contact builder mapping is used mainly to use DEs in Journey builder. firing event will work as soon as there is a new entry recorded in a data extension. So yes, if you are querying master DE and trying to populate a new DE then there is no need to use a fire event. query will populate the new DE itself. Let me know if this is what you wanted to achieve. (just to filter out subscribers from MASTER DE to a new DE used in automation.)

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure everything out the day you first answered my question. Your answer was much appreciated. Thanks!